# Trying to install 32-bit java plugin on Centos 6.5 64-bit mozilla firefox

Tags: java, firefox, centos

Long story short, my employer's webstart VPN requires 32-bit java to launch.  I managed to get this working on a 64-bit CentOS 5.6 vm, but I cannot remember what I did or it's not working on 6.5...

Anyway, I installed Oracle's 32-bit `java` in `/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_11-32-bit`

I have these links:

```
/usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/libjavaplugin.so -> /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_11-32-bit/jre/lib/i386/libnpjp2.so
/usr/lib64/mozilla/plugins/libjavaplugin.so -> /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_11-32-bit/jre/lib/i386/libnpjp2.so
~/.mozilla/libjavaplugin.so -> /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_11-32-bit/jre/lib/i386/libnpjp2.so
```

And they're all intact. The 64-bit java plugin worked (it was in `/usr/lib64/mozilla`)—I got rid of that, first.

`/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_11-32-bit/jre/bin/java` works ok, so I think I have all the compat libs.

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: What's barring you from using an i386 CentOS install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, you forgot to install a 32-bit Firefox!

You cannot run a 32-bit java plugin inside a 64-bit Firefox.